# Why do humans suffer anxiety when they view "Trypophobia trigger images"?

Tags: behaviour, human-evolution, psychology

When you type **Trypophobia Trigger Images** in google, you see a variety of images with irregular lumps and bumps among some more gory images.

Many people report that these images induce phobia like symptoms of anxiety.

Why do we get anxious when exposed to these images? What advantage is there to be had from this response?

I find the reasons like this [ABC news report on ants and spiders](http://bodyodd.nbcnews.com/_news/2011/09/13/7561543-spiders-ants-did-that-make-you-itchy-heres-why?lite). But still didn't get it any info from it.

Comment: I've made some edits to clarify and narrow down the question so that it was at less risk of closure. Interesting question +1.

Comment: Can I post this in Cog sci community or not required? Thank You for editing to my question.

Comment: Generally, it's courteous not to cross post. If there is something you want more information on from my answer, let me know.

Comment: When I searched "trypophobia trigger images" in Google Images, most of the hits that I got were trying to show rotted flesh with maggots and such crawling out of it, as opposed to merely "lumps and bumps".  Is Google showing you something different?

Comment: @Nat That was my edit. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trypophobia) "Trypophobia is a proposed phobia (intense, irrational fear or anxiety) of irregular patterns or clusters of small holes or bumps." The term is somewhat commandeered by online communities that post freaky or gross images.

Comment: I have no reference or anything, only a guess: seeing those holes alone didn't trigger me anything, but when I see "human skin photoshopped with lotus seed", the very first thing that comes to my mind is: *what if it happened to me!?*, and then comes the anxiety (although I'm already used to such images). I think human has tendency to think something bad that may happen to themself that make them anxious.

Comment: @AndrewT. I also have no references, but I definitely agree. Any time I see one of these images, I'm reminded of a bug I learned about that lays its eggs in human skin. If I saw someone with lotus-seed-skin, I think it'd be in my best interests to go nowhere near them; considering natural selection, it seems likely this fear was evolved to help our ancestors avoid diseased individuals.

Comment: I guess one possible explanation is that some people's brains associate those irregular holes or bumps with illness. I don't feel any fear or anxiety, but I do have a slight "yuck" response.

Comment: My student created a neural network for recognizing trypophobia triggers: https://github.com/grzegorz225/trypophobia-detector

Comment: @PiotrMigdal The network achieves ~90% accuracy. Which images from the normal group showed up in the 10% false hits? Or did it seem random?

Comment: @James Usually ones people would mistake as well (e.g. from https://www.reddit.com/r/trypophobia/, but to low res after rescaling to have visible features; or from a "neutral" dataset, but actually being trypophobic). Only other "bad" set of examples was bushes/trees (which can be fixed by putting more of them in the "neutral" dataset). I encourage students (there were 6 of them) to do some write-up, as the results (and other finding) was interesting (and going beyond my expectations). Side note: try neural style: https://deepart.io/ (face as image, lotos seeds as style). A texture phenomenon.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[Trypophobia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trypophobia) is not a recognised specific anxiety disorder ([Washington Post](https://www.washingtonpost.com/national/health-science/phobia-about-holes-is-not-officially-recognized-but-uk-scientists-look-into-it/2012/10/01/c1797a8c-dff0-11e1-a421-8bf0f0e5aa11_story.html?hpid=z5&utm_term=.066845e9022f)). It is worth mentioning that anyone can have a phobia to anything, this is merely a question of whether many people associate these spatial patterns with anxiety. Nevertheless, the response of individuals to these images can be quantified ([Le *et al.,* 2015](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/25635930)). Ultimately the findings show that a response of trypophobia is not correlative with anxiety. Note that here we are discussing anxiety in a phobia response test. Typically anxiety manifests as sweating, dizziness, headaches, racing heartbeats, nausea, fidgeting, uncontrollable crying or laughing and drumming on a desk. This is not merely feeling uncomfortable.

One hypothesis was that these images had irregular spatial patterns that cause revulsion. A study found that in nature some animals and plants may use this patterning as a warning mechanism and that it is associated with poisonous animals  (spatial pattern quantification of 10 poisonous animals versus 10 control animals p=0.03), and indeed spiders were among those that use irregular patterns ([Cole & Wilkins, 2013](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/23982244)). Note that this hypothesis was presented in a psychology journal so the evolutionary mechanisms remain, in my opinion, not fully explored and scrutinised.

Hover over the below yellow box to view a lotus seed head, which has typical irregular spatial patterning presented in the 2013 study.

**This image is often reported as inducing trypophobia.**

> [image]

**Answer**: In summary, humans do not reliably feel anxious when viewing these images. It also remains unclear why some people do get anxious or uncomfortable when viewing these images. It is perhaps to do with an aversion to some potentially harmful animals, but evidence remains scarce.

Comment: I am very much irritated by seeing the image you posted in the answer, I had to close the image with my hands to approve the answer just to click it.

Comment: @user48898: But it doesn't affect me at all.

Comment: Pictures like this make me feel physically sick, not just anxious.

Comment: As a third response class: I don't find the patterns irritating in a manner that makes me feel at all anxious, but I do find them distracting. They draw my gaze if they are in my peripheral vision and set off a "that's odd" feeling that I need to make at least a small amount of conscious effort to ignore. I assume I am subconsciously trying to find a pattern to satiate that part of us that feels safest once everything is understood.

Comment: LOL that's so weird - never noticed it before. I don't feel anxious or sick or anything, but as soon as I hovered over the image and saw it, I had a quick "Ewww" reaction as if I'd just put my hand on something gross. Only lasted a second, but it's still neat to realize the reaction is there.

Comment: Having no references to provide but basing on my reaction to images provided in this answer and answer of gemesyscanada I would argue that it is not the pattern of spots which makes it so gross but rather assumption that it is holes which look like they have been eaten out by something. I have negative response to the image of a flower from this answer, but I have absolutely no problems looking at the salamander from gemesyscanada's answer.

Comment: The image in this answer made me feel anxious but the lizard with the yellow spots did not.  It may be connected to arachnophobia, the spots make me think of spider eyes.

Comment: I wonder if reactions to the specific example of a lotus head are influenced by well-known fake images of lotus heads misrepresented as botfly larva in human skin.

Comment: And here I didn't think I had a reaction to these images... now my chicken tastes weird and I've lost my appetite. Thanks.

Comment: Coincidentally, the only reason I have an issue with the lotus seed is because of a hoax that floated around the internet a few years ago about a skin-eating disease, or bugs that crawl out of skin, or something like that, and they merged an image of a lotus seed with a womans nipple to make this hideous...  Thing...  Ever since then, I can't look at a lotus seed without seeing that image in my head.
Luckily for me, it has not affected my ability to view nipples.

Comment: @jamesqf: Not only do I agree with you, I would go further and say I find this particular shape/texture aesthetically pleasing. I might doodle a plant-like set of irregular holes like that. Clearly I should be careful who I then show that to. I'm not sure what the difference is - I have spent some hobby time crafting computer-generated textures and other artwork like fractals, not sure if that has skewed my appreciations. I generally find pictures of mold/slime/debris unattractive, but not the kind of texture in the image.

Comment: @SGR Here I am discussing anxiety in a phobia test scenario. Sweating, dizziness, headaches, racing heartbeats, nausea, fidgeting, uncontrollable crying or laughing and drumming on a desk are all common manifestations of anxiety.

Comment: @Kevin Krumwiede: Perhaps I have no reaction (other than mild curiousity) to the image because I've never seen those "well-known fake images".

Answer (score 12):

As someone who is very disgusted by this kind of image, I think it is a caused by an association with maladies like burns, infections, and especially parasites. It is difficult for me to even describe this without feeling a bit nauseated, but it is hard for me to see things like that without picturing it being my, or someone else's, skin. Or that it is crawling with parasites. I don't have any particular source for this because it's from my own experience.

It isn't entirely unreasonable that this would be a biological defense because if you saw an animal with an area of perforated skin (also hard to even write) it would be a good idea to not touch it since this could indicate bacterial ulcers or a skin infection. If you saw a patch of ground with tiny holes all over it, it might not be a good idea to sit there as this would probably indicate burrowing insects such as termites were present.

Another thing that confirms this for me is that when trolls edit these patterns onto a human it has the worst effect, and nearly makes me vomit. As [this article](http://www.jordantrudgett.com/all-about-trypophobia/) notes, also from its author's own experience, these types of images are some of the worst for Trypophobia. There have been some studies finding that the response is similar to our [reaction to danger](https://www.psychologicalscience.org/news/releases/fear-of-holes-may-stem-from-evolutionary-survival-response.html), rather that just disgust. From my own reaction to these images this seems to be accurate.

Comment: Please add some references to your answer.

Comment: I have created an account just to upvote this answer. I have exactly the same responses to this images as Paul S. I would theorise the same way Paul S does, images like that give me associations of flesh/substance crawling with larvae and insects, which I would consider dangerous. Places with holes like that give me association of the above mentioned creatures living there which would also be dangerous to approach.

Comment: Also, +1 for “feeling nauseated” (so many people use “nauseous” incorrectly).

Comment: +1 on this, espeically for the photoshops on these patterns. I don't suggest looking at if these pictures do bother, but if you're curious, the [Suriname Sea Toad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Suriname_toad) evokes similar revulsion.

Comment: Welcome to Bio. Thanks for this interesting answer. However, it seems more like a collection of personal thoughts. Could you generalize this answer,  and lift it to the population level, and add sources?

Comment: I'm not sure what I would cite since I am talking about my own feelings on it as someone on which the mentioned patterns have the mentioned effect.

Comment: I realize I could add references to infections and parasites that would cause these kinds of patterns on a creature, but for reasons mentioned in the answer, I really don't want to search for those references.

Comment: @PaulS I agree with AliceD & anotherHomosapien. Without sources, your answer is anecdotal in the first and final paragraph and speculative in the second paragraph.

Comment: Ok, what do you want me to add, specifically?

Comment: Why do you think it is an association with burns and parasites? Since not everyone has the same reaction, you cannot assume disgust is a reasonable response underpinned by a defence mechanism (see Triskaidekaphobia for an example of a phobia that has no clear advantage/defence). I'm also interested; what are these troll images and where can we see them? Is there any evidence that your opinions aren't yours and yours alone? Currently, I'm tempted to flag this as a comment since currently, it is mostly opinion, but I feel like if it can be justified, the community finds this answer valuable.

Comment: "Why do you think it is an association with burns and parasites?" Because that's what it brings to mind when it makes me feel nauseated. "I'm also interested; what are these troll images and where can we see them?" I am not interested in searching out images that nauseate me in order to provide links, I would rather you just delete or downgrade my answer if no one else knows what I'm talking about.

Comment: @user1264176 your personal experience and concurrence with PaulS does not add any weight to the answer. Any answer cannot be based just on feelings/personal experiences and guesses. We need authoritative answers that cite valid references.

Comment: @James well, actually OP has provided search terms for image.google.com search which are even **bold** "Trypophobia Trigger Images" which kind of makes me wonder if you have read the question.

Comment: @user1264176 There are >300,000 images. On the first few pages, some have images overlayed on skin, but in a massive variety. Some are images of pasta. They do not make me personally uncomfortable, yet OP is unable to even google a reference for the images that upset them the most. Without clarification, citation, and expansion, this answer certainly amounts to "I think those images are gross too!" and since the answerer has expressed no interest whatsoever in improving the answer, I think it should be removed.

Comment: @James I have made an edit to this answer because I don't have enough points to make a separate answer. I tried to add references and prove Paul S hypothesis about nausea feeling while looking at these images. Unfortunately, it was rejected. From my search - there is no research in this area, so we can only hypothesise.

Comment: @user1264176 I thought your edits looked good, but it doesn't look like I can accept edits without more points. I could manually change some of them later, but I'm not sure why they were rejected.

Comment: @James "answerer has expressed no interest whatsoever in improving the answer" It's more that I'm not aware of any definitive work on the origin of human emotion. I only said I don't want to add images meant to trigger Trypophobia, but I'll add in some references to people citing similar reasons if that helps.

Comment: @PaulS According to one of the reviewers "This edit deviates from the original intent of the post. Even edits that must make drastic changes should strive to preserve the goals of the post's owner." So if you feel like you want to add my sources and explanations please feel free to do that (+ maybe adopt them to better fit your answer)

Comment: BTW, after reading the articles on jordantrudgett.com and psychologicalscience.org, for the sake of science I have tried to look up all of the images from the authors' list. I got quite bad response only from lotus seeds and maggots removal, all the rest, like octopuses, frogs, frozen peas and rocks give me either no response at all or slight feeling of danger (in case of rocks where something can hide). From this I make a conclusion that I don't have phobia per se, and my responses are more related to danger of creatures living in those holes. This is approximately what I have written in edit

Comment: @PaulS I wasn't asking for a reference that humans have emotions. I am mainly interested in references supporting your idea about contaminated flesh & food. I know of one researcher working on this, but cannot find any published articles. What you've ended up citing is 1-a blog post and 2- a press release about one of the articles from my answer, which you have misrepresented since it doesn't explore your hypothesis at all. The community clearly likes this answer, and I encourage you to expand it so we can remove that banner.

Answer (score 2):

The "That's Odd" feeling is real. And now I understand the term "trypophobia" as a specific example of a more general aversion response which seems common in nature, and might even be hard-wired in the neural-circuits of many animals.  The brightly coloured and mottled/spotted patterns found on various insects, amphibians and reptiles may represent more than just simple camouflage.  I recall a large black salamander I found which was covered by yellow spots - I recognized it as a local species, not rare, but when I noticed it, despite my interest and curiousity, I felt a clear sense of "weird - ugh - yuck".  Now this salamander lives under rocks, under leaves, in rotted-wood, and so on.  The existence of the bright yellow spots are not likely related to helping it hide.  Why would it evolve such a bright pattern, given its typical habitat?  It may be the spot-pattern itself is a weapon, as it seems to provide the creature with a way to trigger a "yuck - leave *that* ugly thing alone" response in humans, who could be potential threats to the small, slow-moving and otherwise quite defenseless salamader.  [image: Yellow Spotted Salamander]  The pattern of spots on the lotus-seed head seem to be similar to the spot pattern on the salamander.  The aversion-response in humans has almost certainly evolved as a protective mechanism to keep us from being poisoned, stung, bitten or burnt when young children. But it is also possible this response is not "hard-wired" at all, but is learned.  Once stung by a brightly-coloured wasp or hornet, the child quickly learns to avoid handling this type of creature.
And the harmless salamander's bright yellow random-spaced spots simply mimic
the colour-coding of more effectively hostile agents.

It is possible the aversion to random spotted bumpy/lumpy surfaces may be related to a similar learning phenomenon.  We encounter stinking, rotted flesh, and already have the evolutionary systems in place to detect that rotted meat should not be eaten - it smells bad.  Really bad.  And so, other creatures have an opportunity to evolve displays which - if they mimic the appearance of the rotted flesh - can benefit by the associative trigger of the visual appearance of the rotten flesh, and the chemical response from the smell.   If the smell creates a powerful aversion response, the linkage that mammals - not just humans - might make to the visual appearance of the bad-smelling thing, might provide an opportunity for creatures to evolve mechanisms that can take advantage of this situation.

This linkage of stimulus-response, and the ability of the stimulus-response mechanism to be transferred to a different, associated response is well understood - Pavlov's dogs, for example, which learned quickly that the ringing bell meant feeding, and so would salivate when they heard the bell ring, without having to smell the food.

It is also possible the trypophobic response some humans feel, is simply learned, the way many phobias appear to be.  The work of B.F. Skinner (creator of the "Skinner Box"), showed that behaviour could be "conditioned", and virtually any stimulus could be made to be associated with any response, given sufficient time, opportunity and intensity of the conditioning effort.

I suspect if a behavioural economist offered to pay $100 for each yellow spotted salamander a person could catch, the typical human would very quickly encode a different internal response to the appearance of the salamander's bumpy, spotted appearance, and it would certainly not be an aversion response.

Comment: Welcome!!! Gemesyscanada to Biology Stack exchange. Please can u provide references to support your statements or for further reading on the topic. You can visit [help center](http://biology.stackexchange.com/help) for more details.

Comment: Excellent answer Gemesyscanada. @Mesentery I am puzzled by this robot like obsession by some on stack exchange to feel compelled to point out technicalities in an otherwise excellent SE answer. Here's a first time poster that has posted what I discern as an excellent answer. And your criticism is more likely to scare him away for nothing. If you want to add refs feel free to edit his answer!

Comment: @curious_cat I just requested him to provide references, I didn't criticise him. I just wanted to give him an idea how the site works by guiding him to the help center. How can u feel that I scared him. Can u point out any threatening word in my comment, that if u don't provide references ur answer will be deleted.

Comment: @gemesyscanada Apologies, if u found my comment in anyway rude or threatening.

Comment: @Mesentery My point is that not every answer needs to have explicit references in it to be a good answer. So long as the point is not very esoteric or controversial it seems counterproductive to stick to a pedantic instance on references. Often a knowledgeable commentor may have enough time to give you a good answer but not enough to search and add for references.

Comment: @curious_cat If this answerer tries to answer an other question which need references, then the first who reviewed the post will be blamed for not guiding the newcomer, therefore it is essential to guide newcomers to the help center. As I said in my above comment, I just requested him. And the mistake I made was not to thank him for his contribution to the site.

Comment: @Mesentery Fair enough. I rest my case.

Comment: Welcome to Biology. It's a nice answer and thank you for your contribution. However, I second the comments from James & Mesentery that references, or sources are considered as an essential component of any answer.